# Connection with the database with figaro is not working on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, figaro-ruby

I am using rails with figaro for configuration, database user with the name **test**. 
I have a `DATABASE_URL` in `application.yml`

```
DATABASE_URL: "postgresql://localhost/database_name?user=test"
```

When I run a

```
rake db:migrate
```

I get the following error

```
PG::ConnectionBad: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

Answer (score 0):

Check `config/database.yml` to ensure your password is wired up for postgresql adapter.

it should look something like this:

```
default:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: foo
  user: bar
  password: <%= ENV['pg_password'] %>
```

`pg_password` should be defined in your figaro config, where it becomes accessible as an environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to emphasize you call the `Figaro ENV` variables in your `.yml` using the `ERB Syntax` :

```
 username: <%= ENV["PG_USERNAME"] %>
  password: <%= ENV["PG_PASSWORD"] %>
```

Hope this helps...!